# Is progress possible by a duo in an infinite maze?

Tags: mazes

Inspired by [Maze Solving Robot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18009/4269) and the related one on [code golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53310/40929). Also [Is progress possible in an infinite maze?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48208/4269)

**Rules**

1. Two people start in the same cell in an orthogonal grid of infinite size.
2. Each cell has four edges, and hence, a maximum of four ways to enter or exit it.
3. Every edge in the grid is either a wall or not a wall.
4. Each person will choose to execute a series of moves, which will consist of 'north', 'south', 'east' and 'west' instructions.
5. If a wall exists in a direction your instruction indicates, the instruction will be skipped.
6. You can assume that there are an infinite number of cells that are accessible from the starting cell; i.e. walls do not box you into some non-infinite subset of cells.
7. The two persons can reside on the same cell or cross each other; their movement ignores each other's existence.

**The Challenge**

> Find a pair of sequences of instructions (of minimum possible total
>   length) - the first to be executed by the first person and the second
>   to be executed by the second person, such that no matter the details
>   of the maze, you can guarantee that atleast one of the two persons
>   doesn't end up at the starting cell, once execution completes.

P.S. I'm not sure this can be done; if it can't, prove that.

Comment: P.S. Turns out the solution is extremely easy. If I get down-voted, I'll delete the post.

Comment: What do you mean you'll delete it if it gets downvoted? SE doesn't work that way, downvotes might mean people don't like the question, but it's not something against *you* personally, not at all.

Comment: @CipherRiddle I know that, but downvotes indicate that the puzzle is too boring, and hence is not an asset to the site. I read a meta post once that said it was fine to delete posts that had negative score.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can do it in just four instructions:

> Person 1: up, left; person 2: down, right.

Comment: You are correct. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, then

> Person 1: (North, East) 
>  Person 2: (South, West)

should work.

> At least one of them must move, and neither can loop back to the start.

Comment: OK damn, you are right. Wish I thought of it.