# Hunter chasing a fox on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, pursuit-evasion

This is a variant of the [sleeping princess puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/455/why-does-this-solution-guarantee-that-the-prince-knocks-on-the-right-door-to-fin).

There are fifteen foxholes, connected by underground tunnels as shown below. A fox is sleeping in one of them.

- Every day, a hunter checks one of the foxholes, finding the fox if it is there.
- Every night, the fox moves through a tunnel to a different, adjacent foxhole.

> How can the hunter catch the fox?

[image]

Comment: Probably the same concept - but instead of odd-even, it's at the nth stage of the binary tree

Comment: For some reason, just seeing 'hunter chasing fox' makes me think of IMOq3

Comment: hunter comes in a day while fox moves in night. so hunter waits for whole day until tomorrow or he checks and go back?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Number the nodes as follows:

[image]

A valid solution is to check:

> 4,2,5,2,1,3,6,3,7,4,2,5,2,1,3,6,3,7

To see that this works, first note that the fox can only go from a hole in an even-numbered level of the tree to a hole in an odd-numbered level of the tree and vice-versa. If the fox starts in an odd level, the sequence 4,2,5,2,1,3,6,3,7 guarantees the hunter will catch it. This works because the hunter alternately looks at a hole at an odd level and then immediately checks the only possible remaining entrance to it, making sure the fox can never return to that hole:

[image]

If the fox has not been caught after this sequence, then you know it is in an even level of the tree. For the next day, it must have moved into a hole in an odd level, so we can use the same sequence again to seal its fate.