Magic Combination lock
To start with, I don't have a solution, and I'm not sure if I unconsciously found this somewhere or I came up with it completely by myself. I did a quicksearch, but can't seem to really find something similar.

Given a magic combination lock, with 3 digits, each has 10 possibilities (0, 1, ..., 9).
When found, the lock will be set so that the first two digits are in the right position. You just need to find the last digit.
However, when you make 3 wrong guesses, all the digits shift one answer up or down (so say the answer is 1;2;3, it can then become any combination of 0/2;1/3;2/4).

Is this mathematically even possible?
If not with 3 attempts, is there a number n (<10) that makes it possible?

If n attempts increases, by a Fibonacci series (3, 5, 8, 13,...) after each failed attempt, at which number would you be able to reliably solve the lock.
(Please explain for someone begining in maths.)


Sorry if I can't ask two questions, I'm mostly interested in the second part. 2) I don't think the first part is reliably solvable, with my basic math skills I'd give it about 33% chance of solving, after that it's pretty much unsolvable (I think).


You can crack the lock almost surely (with arbitrarily close to 100% probability) just by entering random combinations for long enough. We can't guarantee solving it, but the chance we succeed at some point (not in any particular round) is much higher than 33%.

Are 0 and 9 considered adjacent?  If not, then you might be able to win with a smaller n by forcing it to an edge.  The puzzle can be viewed as a 3d analogue of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/455/why-does-this-solution-guarantee-that-the-prince-knocks-on-the-right-door-to-fin and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89160/three-knights-searching-for-a-princess-in-a-castle

@NuclearHoagie The difference between 2 digits will always shift either 0 or 2 from its neighbor.  You would probably guess it faster than random brute force by entering the same first 2 numbers every time, so if its 129, and you guess 121, 122, 123 over and over, the numbers will eventually shift to match, as the 1 and 2 will always be an odd distance apart.  Since you don't know the last number's distance, you have to rotate it.

@ralphmerridew yes, 0 and 9 are considered adjacent.

No, it's not possible to guarantee getting the thing open. You would need at least $9$ guesses before the combination changes to be able to solve it.
The point is that every time it resets, there will now be eight possibilities even if you knew the previous combination. If $n<8$ you can't try all of these before the next reset (and you can't try all $10$ possibilities before the first reset), so you can't guarantee to find the combination after any finite number of attempts.
If $n=8$ then there will still be at least two possibilities when it first resets. But if it resets when there are two possibilities for the combination, there will always be at least $12$ possibilities after reset. (The best case is if the possibilities are something like 123 and 125, leaving options of 012, 014, 016, 032, 034, 036, 212, 214, 216, 232, 234, 236.) So you can't try all but one of these before the next reset, and there will be at least $12$ possibilities after every reset.
You can do it with $n=9$: try nine possibilities, and then it resets but you know what the previous combination must have been so you can try all eight new options in turn.

For the Fibonacci case, the number of possibilities increases quickly at first. But it is never more than $250$, since you always know the parity of the first two digits (it is the same as it was originally after an even number of resets, and opposite after an odd number). So you can easily win in the round where $n=377$. In fact you can win the round before ($n=233$), by using the previous $144$ guesses to eliminate all cases where the last digit is odd. Now you know the parity of all three digits, and so there are now only $125$ options to try.
You might be able to squeeze one better, but I can't see how. For example, a strategy might be to eliminate the last digit being $1$ or $3$ in the round of $55$, which means a last digit of $2$ is already eliminated from the next round. You can then use your $89$ guesses to eliminate last digits of $4$, $6$ and $8$, meaning the only possible last digits in the next round are $0,1,2,4,6,8,9$. But this still leaves $175$ options, and you only have $144$ guesses, so this isn't good enough.

Thanks for the explanation, I had some issues understanding at first, but I think that's due to translation, reading it twice helped.
