An elusive hotel guest
From Building Thinking Classrooms in Mathematics:

An eccentric woman has booked three adjacent and adjoining hotel
rooms. When she checks in, she tells the receptionist that if he needs
her, she will always be in the room next door to the room she was in
the night before.
The receptionist thinks nothing of this until an hour later when he
realizes that her credit card has been declined, and he must now go
find her. The problem is that he is very busy and only has time do
knock on one door per day.
How many days does he need to guarantee that he finds her? What if it
were four rooms? Five rooms? What if it were 17 rooms, and she is
checked in for 30 days - can he find her before she leaves?

My attempt:

The answers for three rooms (2 days) and four rooms (5 days) seem trivial to me. But once we get to five . . . it seems impossible. I have tried to think through many different strategies but it seems that if the woman wants to elude the receptionist, she could! I have been thinking about this problem on and off for over a year and haven't been able to come to a satisfying conclusion.


I think this is essentially the same problem as here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/455/why-does-this-solution-guarantee-that-the-prince-knocks-on-the-right-door-to-fin

Perhaps looking through it and the solution will help.

@hexomino thank you!

I think you can do four rooms in four days, using the strategy in the linked question.  Doors 2, 3, 3, 2.

In general, it takes $2(n-2)$, or $2n-4$ attempts.  Thus 17 rooms in thirty days: $2(17)-4=30$.
